# Regular expression fails when same characters are repeated

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to execute following code :

```
var pwd = "CURRENT DATE - 23 DAYS";
var Exp = /^([CURRENT]{7}[ ]{1}[DATE]{4}[ ]{1}[-]{1}[ ]{1}[\d]+[ ]{1}[DAYS]{4})$/i;
var Exp2 = /^([CURRENT]{7}[ ]{1}[DATE]{4}[ ]{1}[-]{1}[ ]{1}[\d]+[ ]{1}[MONTHS]{6})$/i;

if (pwd.match(Exp) || pwd.match(Exp2)) {
    alert("SUCCESS");
} else {
    alert("ERROR");
}
```

It works as expected... But though I have given first-word `CURRENT` and mentioned 7 characters, It accepts if I give the wrong word like `CUUUENT` instead of `CURRENT`. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sub-expression `[CURRENT]{7}` is saying repeat any of the letters in the set [CURRENT] seven times. What I think you meant to intend was to match the string CURRENT. That would just be `CURRENT`.

Much of your regular expressions are specifying the same thing. `/^CURRENT DATE - [0-9]+ (DAYS|MONTHS)$/` should match what you have well enough.

Answer (score 2):

With `[CURRENT]{7}` you match every character from `[]`, and 7 of them. If you want to match the whole word, use `(CURRENT)`

It'd be better with  `(CURRENT DATE - \d{1} DAYS)`

Note that whn you writr the whole word, it matches kt exactly as it it written. But `[THIS]{4}` captures any combination of 4 letters between `[]` like `ITHS` or `HHHT`.

Comment: That last part should be `\d+ DAYS`: one or more digits and one space (the  `{1}`  never needed to be there).